# Fortawesome reactjs icon colors in css

Tags: css, reactjs, colors, font-awesome, centralized

I have several Fontawesome tags spread across several components. Their color attribute is currently being hard-coded to a custom color HEX code. I want to centralize this color code in css, so that if needed I would just change it one place. Is this possible?

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faThumbsUp} 
                        size="sm" color="#7ACC35"/>
```

Comment: You can create central class for that. In future if you want to update any specific style it will update from there. You dont have to worry about anywhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you could do that, just use `className` and define your in css file

```
.CustomColor {
  color: red;
}

.CustomColor2 {
  color: green;
}

.CustomColor3 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} size="4x" className="CustomColor" />
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} size="4x" className="CustomColor2" />
<FontAwesomeIcon icon={faCoffee} size="4x" className="CustomColor3" />
```

Codesandbox demo

[image: Edit muddy-lake-osyi8]